# How to add search option in android application?

Tags: android, search

I am developing an android application in android in which i want to use search option with which i can search particular data item either from web services or from a database  ?

Comment: Can you provide more information as to what exactly you are trying to achieve with the search?

Comment: I have to make search functionality in my application the data came from webservices but now i want only search dialog in my application i am unable to make that search dialog in my app so can you suggest me any solution

Comment: @Amandeep singh - What I would suggest is to parse the information from your webservice into a SQLLite database, where you can then perform search queries including full text search. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Create an XML file named list_item.xml and save it inside the res/layout/ folder. Edit the file to look like this:

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textColor="#000">
</TextView>
```

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Country" />
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**java**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

  AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)  findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Inside the HelloAutoComplete class, add the string array:**

```
  static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
   "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",};
```

Comment: This looks good. But this isn't enough to make your search box (search dialog) implement it, right? I mean search dialog is an inbuilt feature, may be a simple `EditText`. Can you tell me how do I make my quick search box extend this `AutoCompleteTextView`?

Answer (score 3):

**Searching inside your database**

SQLLite provides built in functionality to allow for full text searching

- http://bakhtiyor.com/2009/08/sqlite-full-text-search/

**From a webservice**

As far as searching via a webservice normally you simply send the search terms to the server via your webservice, the server performs the search and you parse the response.

**Lucene**

Unless what you are REALLY asking about is a search index, where you may have keywords that allows you to quickly index a large database, or a webservice as the data may not be duplicated between the two.

In which case you can use LUCENE

- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/introduction-to-apache-lucene-for-full.html

However to get lucene to work with Android you may need to check out the source and remove a few depenencies with RMI.

See the bottom of this page for the solution (only need to remove 2 files and it should compile and work with Android).

- http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/601329551a87e601

**How to implement the search dialog box**

The developers guide only gives you enough to start implementing the interface to your search dialog box.  Read through the example source code (posted below) to see how it fits together into an application.

Android Developers Guide

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Example Code

- http://sampleandroidapps.com/searchable-dictionary-source-code-download.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggesions but can you told me how can i make search dialog in my application i had search from this link http://android.ankara-gtug.org/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html but i did'nt understans.

Comment: @Amandeep singh - Are you a different person to @Avi Kumar Manku? If not could you please add this extra information into the question.  Effectively then I would ask you to provide code to show what you have done so far, what errors/exceptions that you have.

Comment: No i am not Avi should i ask question in the same way or i can ask from you with my Id

Comment: @Amandeep singh - I'd recommend asking a new question if you cannot find an answer already on stack overflow for the problem that you have.  Include source code and the specific problem that you have.  Here is an example application which shows how to implement and use the Search feature. [http://sampleandroidapps.com/searchable-dictionary-source-code-download.html](http://sampleandroidapps.com/searchable-dictionary-source-code-download.html)

Comment: thanks for this. I am new to android so sometime i get stuck in a problems so can you join my chatroom so that i can discuss my problem in a bit more detail My chatroom is (learn_andrid). i had just created this.

Answer (score 1):

Use edittext with a button or auto complete text view with a button.

Load data from a file or database for the auto complete part. Once you obtain the data, pass it to the web-service call or search your local database for the same.

Hope I got the requirement right and helped you.

Comment: This looks good. But this isn't enough to make your search box (search dialog) implement it, right? I mean search dialog is an inbuilt feature, may be a simple EditText. Can you tell me how do I make my quick search box extend this AutoCompleteTextView?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the search dialog; see the following link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html
also:
http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-implementing-search-activities/